# Django: cкачать FileField

Tags: python, pdf, django

Есть модель:

```
class Newspaper(models.Model):
    full_pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='pdf', blank=True, null=True)
```

И есть некоторая function view, что бы скачать этот файл(pdf):

```
def pdf(request):
    # Много логики
    n = Newspaper.objects.get(pk=pk)
    # Много логики
    pdf_file = n.full_pdf

    response = HttpResponse(pdf_file, mimetype='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="News_' + n.issue + '_' + tp + '.pdf"')
    return response
```

Беда в том, что скачивается либо 0 байт, либо неполный файл. Изредка полчается получить полную версию.

Что сделано не правильно?

Comment: Content-Length в ответе верный?

Comment: @Fike Content-Length вобще в ответе нету

Comment: @Антон Феоктистов, этот заголовок указывает на размер документа, попробуйте добавить его, используя размер файла (хотя и без него работать должно).  
в `pdf_file` точно лежит то, что нужно?

Comment: @Fike точно. Дебажил итоговый путь - всё правильно, файл на месте

Comment: Если ещё актуально, попробуйте заменить в `response`  `mimetype` на `content_type`. Я не гуру и не могу точно сказать, где ошибка, но у меня всё работает с `content_type`.